# $n$ distinct objects in $k$ boxes, and methods for solving combinatorics problems

Tags: combinatorics

I am a beginner in the subject of combinatorics and would like to know a few things. 
A) Someone please explain me how we get the K to the nth number of ways of distributing n distinct objects in k boxes.

B) When do we use the following methods:
   a+b+c+..+n = x  ; and
   (1 + x + x^2 + x^3+...) to the power something

Comment: I don't understand part (B). The first is rather specific, in the second are you asking about virtually the entire theory of generating functions or...?

Comment: Maybe a book like Path to Combinatorics for Undergraduates will help?

Answer (score 2):

About 1: You get $k^n$ since for each of the $n$ elements you have $k$ choices (you choose the box), so you have $k\cdot k\cdots k$ exactly $n$ times (this is "the product principle" of combinatorics in action).

In 2 I think you're confusing the notation. The basic idea here is this: suppose you have the equation $a+b=n$ where $a,b$ can get every nonnegative integer value. One way to find the number of solutions is to compute the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(x^0+x^1+x^2+x^3+\dots)(x^0+x^1+x^2+x^3+\dots)$.

Here the first parenthesis represents the values that can $a$ can get, in the exponent of $x$; the second parenthesis represents values $b$ can get.

Now, to generalize this, all you need to do is add more parenthesis - one for each variable in the original equation - and maybe remove some elements from specific parenthesis. For example, if we have the equation $a+b+c=n$ and we demand that $a$ is odd and $b$ is even (and $c$ whatever), this is described by
$$(x^1+x^3+x^5+\dots)(x^0+x^2+x^4+\dots)(x^0+x^1+x^2+x^3+\dots)$$

(Note the exponents).